# How to get elements of an array that is not null

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I am doing gift (String-type) storage, using arrays, with the maximum 500 million. I want to get the number of used elements in an array like how many gifts are currently in stock, (I.E. I stored 253538 gifts, but I don't know that. Is there a command in Java that can know that there is only 253538 Slots in the array that contain an element). But I don't know how to. Here's the snippet of code I want to use:

```java
static String[] Gifts = new String[500000000];
static int i = 0;
String command, Gift;
while (true) {
    //Gift Array Console
    String command = scan.next();
    if (command == "addgift") {
        String Gift = scan.next();
        Gifts[i] = Gift;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the array and count the non-null array elements.

```java
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i ++) {
    if (arrayName[i] != null)
        counter ++;
}
```

Also it would be even better if you used `ArrayList<String>` so you could use `size()`

```
List<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>(20);
System.out.println(arrayName.size());
```

It will print `0`, as there are no elements added to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) to iterate over this *array of strings*, then use [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to select [`nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-) elements and [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) them:

```java
String[] arr = {"aaa", null, "bbb", null, "ccc", null};

long count = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(Objects::nonNull).count();

System.out.println(count); // 3
```

---

Or if you want to find the index of the first `null` element to insert some value there:

```java
int index = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> arr[i] == null)
        .findFirst()
        .getAsInt();

arr[index] = "ddd";

System.out.println(index); // 1
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [aaa, ddd, bbb, null, ccc, null]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to find duplicate elements in array in effective way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344781/14838237)</sup>